# Witadmin error : you are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com/my-orgnization

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I'm facing a problem exporting configurations with the witadmin tool

```
witadmin exportcategories /p:https://dev.azure.com/my-org /p:my-proj :f/"file-path"
```

```
output : 
you are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com/my-orgnization
```

I have tried logging out from the visual studio and re-log in, id did not work.

Answer (score 0):

According to this doc for [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-categories?view=azure-devops#syntax),  you will need to use `/collection:https://dev.azure.com/my-org` to configure your organization.

```
witadmin exportcategories /collection:CollectionURL /p:Project [/f:FileName] [/e:Encoding]   
  
witadmin importcategories /collection:CollectionURL /p:Project /f:FileName [/e:Encoding]
```

And for `you are not authorized to access`, I suggest that you could restart your machine or use another machine to test the command again. The error message could be resulted from the credential cache.